How to request permissions to Android in Unity?
I made android unity game, that sometimes working with file system, creating new folder and files, editing those files. When I was testing this on android device, nothing happened with files. I know, the problem is my app does not has android permissions to editing files. Idk how to asking permissions, help me pls
I was trying to ask this permissions by UnityEngine.Android.Permission.RequestUserPermission(UnityEngine.Android.Permission.ExternalStorageRead); but nothing changes.

Two things.
One: The RequestUserPermission includes a callback that gets ran when the user acts on your permission request, the game execution does not pause to wait for the user to accept/deny. This means that you're most likely still executing the file operations before the user has the chance to hit accept or deny.
Try putting your file operations in the callbacks:
var callbacks = new PermissionCallbacks();
callbacks.PermissionGranted += (permissionName) => {
  // Perform file operations here
};
Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageWrite, callbacks);


Two: ExternalStorageWrite is a separate permission than ExternalStorageRead
